# Trying to install cinnamon and getting a dependency error

Tags: 12.04, dependencies, cinnamon

Trying to install cinnamon 1.6.4 using `apt-get install cinnamon` and I'm getting this error. How can I resolve this error?

```
cinnamon : Depends: gir1.2-muffin-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libgjs0-libmozjs185-1.0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libgjs0c (>= 1.34.0) but 1.32.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-4 (>= 3.2.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmuffin0 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: nemo but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please adding some detail, Ubuntu version, cinnamon version...

Comment: How can I check what version of cinnamon I'm trying to install? I was grabbing it from this ppa sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable.

Comment: Open terminal and type: cinnamon –version . Please update your question and adding the details.